# Múltiplos Resultados com dois critérios

Tags: microsoft-excel

Galera estou com uma dúvida em excel. Tenho uma tabela com as colunas "Vendedor", "Cliente" e "Cidade". gostaria de obter um modo de ver todos os resultados obtidos,  para um determinado Vendedor em uma determinada cidade, ou seja, ver todos os clientes desse vendedor nessa cidade.

Preciso desse resultado em células, sem sem por tabela dinâmica, de modo que o usuário selecione através de uma Lista os valores possíveis para "Vendedor" e "Cidade"

Alguém pode me ajudar?

PS: Um problema é que pode existir um mesmo cliente em cidades diferentes com vendedores diferentes

Comment: Tentou usar formatação condicional? e fazer as listas onde ira variar conforme cada vendedor?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isto? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5tyAo77M_U

Comment: as sublistas resolvem o problema em partes. Mas como eu preciso de um efeito em cadeia maior (são 3 critérios encadeados) elas não resolvem